# How to render Multiple NavBar in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am new to react. I am trying to render multiple navbar in my page one beneath the other. My navbar code looks like the following

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../action_creators';
import subNav from './subNavbar.jsx';

class MainNav extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         loggedIn: 1,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
             <div>
                <Navbar inverse fixedTop collapseOnSelect>
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <a href="/">SportsSpot</a>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                    </Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Collapse>
                        <Nav>
                            <LinkContainer to="/nfl" activeClassName="active">
                               <NavItem onClick={this.props.getCurrentNFLNews} eventKey={1}>NFL</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <LinkContainer to="/mlb" activeClassName="active">
                               <NavItem onClick={this.props.getCurrentMLBNews} eventKey={2}>MLB</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <LinkContainer to="/nba" activeClassName="active">
                               <NavItem onClick={this.props.getCurrentNBANews} eventKey={3}>NBA</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <LinkContainer to="/nhl" activeClassName="active">
                               <NavItem onClick={this.props.getCurrentNHLNews} eventKey={4}>NHL</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>   
                        </Nav>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                        <LinkContainer to="/login">
                                <NavItem>Login</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                        <LinkContainer to="/signup">
                            <NavItem>Sign Up</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                    </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>

                <subNav/> // Adding subnavbar code here

                <div className="content">
                        {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

MainNav.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
  getCurrentNHLNews : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getCurrentMLBNews : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getCurrentNFLNews : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getCurrentNBANews : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null,actionCreators)(MainNav);
```

And my subnavbar has the following code

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../action_creators';

class subNav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <Navbar collapseOnSelect>
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            NFL
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                    </Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Collapse>
                        <Nav>
                            <LinkContainer to="/scores">
                               <NavItem>Scores</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <LinkContainer to="/schedules">
                               <NavItem>Schedule</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <LinkContainer to="/standings">
                               <NavItem >Standings</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <LinkContainer to="/stats">
                               <NavItem>Stats</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer> 
                            <LinkContainer to="/teams">
                               <NavItem>Teams</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>  
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null,actionCreators)(subNav);
```

I want to render this subnavbar beneath the main navbar. I tried importing the subnavbar.jsx in the main navbar and added  but it doesn't seem to render. I am also adding my routes code below

```
const routes =<div>
    <MainNav>
    <App>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePageContainer}/>
        <Route exact path="/nfl" component={SubSportsHomePageContainer}/>
        <Route exact path="/nhl" component={SubSportsHomePageContainer}/>
        <Route exact path="/nba" component={SubSportsHomePageContainer}/>
        <Route exact path="/mlb" component={SubSportsHomePageContainer}/>
        <Route path ="/login" component = {LoginPage}/>
        <Route path ="/signup" component = {SignUpPage}/>
    </Switch>
    </App> 
</MainNav>
<subNav>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/scores" component={Scores}/>
            <Route exact path="/schedules" component={Schedule}/>
            <Route exact path="/standings" component={Standings}/>
            <Route exact path="/stats" component={Stats}/>
            <Route path ="/teams" component = {Teams}/>
        </Switch>
</subNav>
</div>
```

I do know what mistake am I committing. Thanks for the help in advance